# Error HRESULT E_FAIL when creating Exchange mailbox (CDOEXM.IMailboxStore.CreateMailbox)

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, exchange-server

I am trying to automate the process of creating an Exchange Mailbox for AD users and am running into an issue.  When calling the CreateMailbox method I am receiving the error "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component".  I have installed and referenced the Exchange Management Tools and am using impersonation for permissions.

Here is the code:

```
            ActiveDs.IADsUser adUser = (ActiveDs.IADsUser)user.NativeObject;
            adUser.AccountDisabled = !Active;
            user.CommitChanges();

            //Set Password
            user.Invoke("SetPassword", Password);
            user.CommitChanges();            

            //Create Mailbox
            IMailboxStore mailbox;
            mailbox = (IMailboxStore)adUser;
            mailbox.CreateMailbox("LDAP://CN=StandardUsers,CN=StandardUsers,CN=InformationStore,CN=xxxxx," +
                "CN=Servers,CN=First Administrative Group,CN=Administrative Groups," +
                "CN=xxxxx Main,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=xxxxx,DC=com");             
            user.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

My original response was kinda wack; I totally misread the code.  What you have is similar to what we had working in production back during Exch 2003.  We called the code from a web service that ran as an account that had admin privileges in AD and Exchange.

Anyhow, this is what MSDN is saying now [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142616(EXCHG.65).aspx):

**Important**  Because of issues with multiple-hop authentication and unexpected results observed in multithreaded runtime environments, Microsoft® does not support using CDO for Exchange Management (CDOEXM) in Microsoft ASP.NET pages, ASP Web pages or in Web services. To create Web-based Microsoft Exchange management applications that use CDOEXM functionality, Microsoft recommends wrapping CDOEXM in a Distributed Component Object Model (DCOM) package and calling that package from your application.

Comment: adUser is an IADsUser object, user is the DirectoryEntry

Comment: From what I understand, DirectoryEntry is a .NET wrapper around ADSI object, in this case, the IADsUser.  And according to MSDN, the NativeObject property of DirectoryEntry:  "gets the native Active Directory Service Interfaces (ADSI) object."